# Get url and body from IncomingMessage?

Tags: node.js, http

I am very new to node. I am at the point at which I have a simple server which should just print the request **query** and the request **body** which it takes. What I've understood is that the "handle request" function actually doesn't return a *request object*, rather an `IncomingMessage` object.

There are two things which I don't understand: How to obtain the *query string* and the *body*.

I get just the path, without the query and undefined for the body.

Server Code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log("Request query  " + request.url);
  console.log("Request body  " + request.body);
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Request code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/',
  query: "argument=narnia",
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('response: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write("<h1>Hello!</h1>");
req.end();
```

Please note that I am a complete beginner. I am not looking for express only solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you do not see the query string at `request.url` is that you aren't sending one correctly.  In your request code, [there is no `query` property of `options`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).  You must [append your querystring to the `path`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html).

```
path: '/' + '?' +  querystring.stringify({argument: 'narnia'}),
```

For your second question, if you want the full request body, you must read from the request object like a stream.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // Do something with `chunk` here
  });
});
```